# How to draw over browser screen with Konva?

Tags: javascript, konva

I wrote a script with Konva that can draw arrows with captions in the browser window. But when I run this script on my web page (it's a panoramic tour made in pano2vr app, if it matters), the tour image first disappears, the screen turns white, and only after that I can draw in the window.
How to make the image on the screen not disappear, but the arrows are drawn on top of the image?
https://youtu.be/ygntnc9xrA8

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@9.2.0/konva.min.js"></script>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
    
        var stage = new Konva.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: width,
            height: height
        });
    
        var layer = new Konva.Layer();
        stage.add(layer);
    
        var line = new Konva.Line({
            stroke: '#510e72',
            strokeWidth: 4,
            dash: [10, 10]
        });
        layer.add(line);
    
        var isDrawing = false;
        var points = [];
        var arrows = [];
        var inputFields = [];
    
        stage.on('mousedown', function(e) {
            if (e.evt.button === 0) {
                isDrawing = true;
                var pos = stage.getPointerPosition();
                points = [pos.x, pos.y];
            }
        });
    
        stage.on('mousemove', function(e) {
            if (!isDrawing) {
                return;
            }
            var pos = stage.getPointerPosition();
            line.points([pos.x, pos.y, points[0], points[1]]);
            layer.batchDraw();
        });
    
        stage.on('mouseup', function(e) {
            if (!isDrawing) {
                return;
            }
            if (e.evt.button === 0) {
                isDrawing = false;
    
                var pos = stage.getPointerPosition();
                points.push(pos.x, pos.y);
    
                var arrow = new Konva.Arrow({
                    points: points,
                    pointerLength: 20,
                    pointerWidth: 20,
                    fill: '#510e72',
                    stroke: '#510e72',
                    strokeWidth: 4
                });
    
                layer.add(arrow);
                line.points([]);
                layer.batchDraw();
    
                var inputField = document.createElement('textarea');
                inputField.style.position = 'absolute';
                inputField.style.left = points[0] + 'px';
                inputField.style.top = points[1] + 'px';
                inputField.style.resize = 'none';
                inputField.style.overflow = 'auto';
                inputField.style.backgroundColor = '#555';
                inputField.style.color = '#fff';
                inputField.style.border = 'none';
                inputField.style.padding = '3px';
                inputField.style.margin = '0';
                inputField.style.font = '14px Arial';
                inputField.style.borderRadius = '5px';
                document.body.appendChild(inputField);
                inputField.focus();
    
                inputField.addEventListener('input', function() {
                    inputField.style.height = 'auto';
                    inputField.style.height = inputField.scrollHeight + 'px';
                });
    
    
                arrows.push(arrow);
                inputFields.push(inputField);
            }
        });
    
        stage.on('contextmenu', function(e) {
            e.evt.preventDefault();
    
            var target = e.target;
            if (target instanceof Konva.Arrow) {
                var arrowIndex = arrows.indexOf(target);
                if (arrowIndex > -1) {
                    var arrow = arrows[arrowIndex];
                    arrow.destroy();
                    arrows.splice(arrowIndex, 1);
    
                    var inputField = inputFields[arrowIndex];
                    inputField.parentNode.removeChild(inputField);
                    inputFields.splice(arrowIndex, 1);
                }
            }
    
            var target = e.target;
            if (target instanceof Konva.Arrow) {
                target.remove();
                layer.batchDraw();
            } else if (target instanceof Konva.Tag) {
                var inputFieldIndex = inputFields.indexOf(target);
                if (inputFieldIndex > -1) {
                    var inputField = inputFields[inputFieldIndex];
                    inputField.parentNode.removeChild(inputField);
                    inputFields.splice(inputFieldIndex, 1);
                }
            }
    
        });

</script>
```